# How to update API resource Laravel?

Tags: laravel, request, postman, crud, api-design

[image]I have used built in `resource` method on my routes for a particular controller to generate standard CRUD routes, but I can't figure out how to update a resource. I'm trying to create an API, so I am using `App\Http\Resources`, not just models. Here is the code in my controller attempting to update, but it does not work:

```
public function update(Request $request, Sample $sample)
{
    $sample = Sample::where('id', $request->id)->update($request->all());   
}
```

I'm using postman to check my routes, and I'm attempting a `put` request with raw updated JSON to app.dev/api/samples/1 but after putting a `get` request to same url I can see that values have not changed. 
How can I make this update work?

EDIT: Here is my api.php routes file

```
Route::resource('samples', 'SampleController');
```

Comment: Why are you adding Sample object as the function parameter without using it inside function ?

Comment: This is how it was when I created resource controller

Comment: If you are not using it in the function and just remove that, everything looks right can you add you api.php content please

Comment: One more thing, did you passed id in the request ?

Comment: I have tried it, but it does not fix issue

Comment: can you run `php artisan route:list` and add the output, and also the content of sample model

Comment: Here is the output for `route:list`, specifically `api          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | api/samples/{sample}      | samples.update  | App\Http\Controllers\SampleController@update`. The sample model is empty

Comment: Thats good, for update you need to make column fillable I'll add the code in answer have a look.

Answer (score 4):

in your header in postman try to input like this, i use x-www-form-urlencoded:

```
Key                  Value                            Description
Accept          application/json
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

in your body in postman try use x-www-form-urlencoded:

```
key         value
name        update
content     new content
```

Comment: I had the same problem with postman using form-data. Changing it to x-www-form-urlencoded was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define column as fillable in the model so that they can be updated later. All you need to do is to add following line in Sample Model.

```
protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'content'];
```

If this still don't work, feel free to ask.

Comment: @hoolakoola Then I don't  know why and whats wrong :D

Comment: Thank you anyway! Solved it by removing the store and update routes from the resource call in api.php, setting them myself, and using the store method for both store and update route.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this. Hopefully this will solve your problem,

```
public function update(Request $request, Sample $sample)
{
    $sample = $sample->update($request->all());   
}
```

Comment: The first example does not work, and the second is the same as below, but also does not work.

Comment: @hoolakoola I have updated my answer please take a look

Answer (score 0):

If this is a standard Laravel resource route/controller and your endpoint is `api/samples/1`
then your PATCH/PUT update method should look something like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $sample = Sample::find($id);
    $sample->update($request->all());
}
```

If your body is JSON then you will probably need:

`$sample->update($request->json()->all());`